# hadoop MapReduce: find max key value pair from output of mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

It sounds like a simple job, but with MapReduce it doesn't seem that straight-forward.

I have *N* files in which there is only one line of text for each file.  I'd like the Mapper to output key value pairs like < filename, score >, in which 'score' is an integer calculated from the line of text.  As a sidenote I am using the below snippet to do so (hope it's correct).

```
 FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
 String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

Assuming the mapper does its job correctly, it should output *N* key value pairs.
Now the problem is **how should I program the Reducer to output the one key value pair with the maximum 'score'**?

From what I know Reducer only works with key value pairs that share the same key.  Since the output in this scenario all have different keys, I am guessing something should be done before the Reduce step.  Or perhaps should the Reduce step be omitted altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the setup() and cleanup() methods (configure() and close() methods in old API).
Declare a global variable in reduce class, which determines the maximum score. For each call to reduce, you would compare the input value (score) with the global variable.

Setup() is called once before all reduce invocations in the same reduce task. Cleanup() is called after last reduce invocation in the same reduce task. So, if you have multiple reducers, Setup() and cleanup() methods would be called separately on each reduce task.

Comment: Not complete in the approach. If there are multiple reducers, then each one will emit the maximum value in a particular file as the output. Again this has to be sorted and the maximum value found out. Or set the number of reducers to 1.

Comment: I have a question: shouldn't there still be N outputs (since every Reducer should write out its own results)?  And even if the number of Reducer is 1, I don't think that Reducer is willing to take all the key-value pairs.

Comment: If you configure just one reducer, this works very fine. No need to downvote.

Comment: @yongtw123 if you configure just 1 reducer, the hashpartitioner can just assign every key/value pair to this one reducer. So every k/v pair will be available there. But Praveen is right, it is limited in scalability. But for two files it would be totally okay.

Comment: Since the data I need to process is not extremely large, this simple solution works for me.  Thank you!

Comment: @Downvoter : Can you please tell whats the reason for down voting?

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume that

File1 has 10,123,23,233

File2 has 1,3,56,1234

File3 has 6,1,3435,678

---

Here is the approach for finding the maximum number from all the input files.

1. Lets first do some random sampling (like say every N records). From File1 123 and 10, from File2 56 and 1, from File3 1 and 678.
2. Pick the maximum number from the random sampling, which is 678.
3. Pass the maximum number from the random sampling to the mapper and ignore the input numbers less the maximum number found in the random sampling and emit the others in the mappers. Mappers will ignore anything less than 678 and emit 678, 1234 and 3435.
4. Configure the job to use 1 reducer and find the max of all the numbers sent to the reducer. In this scenario reducer will receive 678, 1234 and 3435. And will calculate the maximum number to be 3435.

---

Some observations of the above approach

1. The data has to be passed twice.
2. The data transferred between the mappers and reducers is decreased.
3. The data processed by the reducers also decreases.
4. Better the input sampling, faster the Job completes.
5. Combiner with similar functionality as the Reducer will further improve the Job time.

Comment: This is not exactly what my problem is, but still thanks for the insight.

Comment: What's the difference? I thought you wanted to find out the maximum score from all the input files.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the the filename and the score as the value and just return any constant as the key from your mapper

Comment: To elaborate, so what you suggest is to create a new Writable object to store both filename and score and use it in bother Mapper and Reducer?

Comment: I am able to create my custom Writable class, but can you provide an example of how to use this custom Writable with the Mapper and Reducer class?  For example what should I do in context.write()?  Resources I find is very vague on this.

Comment: You use the setMapOutputValueClass of the JobConf . There's a good explanation here http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html

Comment: Or have the number of reducers set to 1 with the approach yongtw123 mentioned in the OP. But, the problem is there is only one reducer, would be a bottle neck with huge data.

Comment: @PraveenSripati you can do some of the work with combiners (get local max for each map) and get the max of these in the reducer

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz - Pl check the other approach I mentioned in the answers by sampling the data before doing the actual work of finding the maximum.

Comment: I'd tried your solution, but I've encountered some difficulties (due to my rudimentary skills in MapReduce). Still I believe this should be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Refer slide 32 & 33 of http://www.slideshare.net/josem.alvarez/map-reduceintro

I used the same approach and got the result. Only concern is when you have multiple fields, you need to create fieldnamemin and fieldnamemax individually.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the Reducer !!
Use the Configuration to set the global variable as score and key and then access it in the mapper to do a simple selection of max score by using the global variable as the memory of max score and key
It should be simple. I guess.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ok... Thanks :-) (Btw, smileys are allowed or not ? I am new to the forum.)

Comment: @DheerajVerma Emoticons and smileys are discouraged. Also, this is not a forum, but a focused site for questions and answers. One of the main ways this is evident is that every post is either a question, a direct answer, or a comment associated with that post that asks for clarification or clarifies. Unlike forums, there is no linear set of posts, and answers can be reordered based on their votes or activity.